# Compiling sass file "Error: Expected spaces, was tabs."

Tags: html, css, syntax, sass, whitespace

I got my `sass` files from another user in the project, and have just started to modify them. When I compile, I get this error for the line below my added line:

> Error: Expected spaces, was tabs.

However, all the white space is tabs. According to my editor, Brackets, and has been working fine for weeks.

Why does this matter enough to thrown an error? 
(It's fixed easily enough with a Find/Replace.)

Comment: Here is the code that contains that error message: https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/blob/master/lib/src/parse/sass.dart#L400

Comment: You will get that even if you have just one extra space accidentally entered. Find a plugin for brackets to convert all spaces to tabs and you will be fine

Comment: @yunzen This points to a wrong place now. Permalink: https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/blob/e87176a52aaf3ca4f7f3fe53612ac1ee58aee1ce/lib/src/parse/sass.dart#L465

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consistent indentation is a good code style. Especially if you mix spaces and tabs and share the files with other people, it could get wild.

An [`.editorconfig`](https://editorconfig.org/) file might help you, if your editor (and your coworkers editors) understand it